# Highchart Json Format for Highchart stock chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

From the [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/) given by highcharts the Json format for highStock is:

```
[
[1237766400000,174.13],
[1237852800000,173.41],
[1237939200000,171.86],
[1238025600000,176.47],
[1238112000000,173.68],
[1238371200000,171.17],
[1238457600000,173.86]
]
```

But I want to put the name of the series inside the Json data as:

```
[
    {"name":"USD"},
     {"data":
      [
        [1237766400000,174.13],
        [1237852800000,173.41],
        [1237939200000,171.86],
        [1238025600000,176.47],
        [1238112000000,173.68],
        [1238371200000,171.17],
        [1238457600000,173.86]
      ]
     }
]
```

Here is my Code:

```
var  currCodeArray = ['USD']

$.each(currCodeArray, function(i, currCode) {

        $.getJSON('//servername/GetHighChartData.ashx?currCode='+currCode, function(data) {
            createChart(data);
         });
    });

    function createChart(data) {

      $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

          yAxis: {
            opposite: false,
            labels: {
              format: '{value:.2f}'
            }

          },

          legend: {
            enabled: true
          },
          series: data

        });
      }
```

Problem is I see the chart as:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending data in

```
[
{"name":"USD"},
 {"data":
  [
    [1237766400000,174.13],
    [1237852800000,173.41],
    [1237939200000,171.86],
    [1238025600000,176.47],
    [1238112000000,173.68],
    [1238371200000,171.17],
    [1238457600000,173.86]
  ]
 }
]
```

format basically means you are sending data for two different series, since there are two objects in the array.
Change  it to

```
[
{"name":"USD",
 "data":
  [
    [1237766400000,174.13],
    [1237852800000,173.41],
    [1237939200000,171.86],
    [1238025600000,176.47],
    [1238112000000,173.68],
    [1238371200000,171.17],
    [1238457600000,173.86]
  ]
 }
]
```

Notice that I have removed the curly brackets after "USD" and before "data".